# PHPMyadmin tool slow in importing

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

One of my customer reports that while importing a 1mb CSV file it takes more than the usual time (more than 30 min) which is abnormal. While using the format type as `CSV using LOAD DATA` it throws an error.

SQL query

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/phpzfQQR8' INTO TABLE `course1` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
1085 - The file '/tmp/phpzfQQR8' must be in the database directory or be readable by all
```

It actually works the other way but just abnormally slow. Could someone help me on this really quick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CSV using LOAD DATA`, try just `CSV`.